# Perl module or method to create DVD compliant ISO from directory without system commands

Tags: linux, perl, dvd

Are there any Perl modules or combination of modules to create DVD compliant ISOs? This will run on Linux and I'm not concerned about portability. What I'm looking to do is create a DVD compliant ISO from a directory that contains a VIDEO_TS directory structure. The solution would not need to rip an actual DVD.

What I currently run is:

```
genisoimage -V 'Name_of_DVD' -dvd-video -o dvd.iso /some_directory
```

I am aware of Perl ability to run external commands:

```
system function
exec function
backticks (``) operator
open function
```

There is also CPAN the CPAN module `Filesys::MakeISO::Driver::Mkisofs` which uses genisoimage/mkisofs. What I specifically want is a solution that does **NOT** use linux/OS commands. If there are no such solutions or the solution is overly complex then please state that. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter, I don't see anything especially wrong with this question. The solution, as I post, might be simple, yet perhaps someone has some other idea.

Comment: @JoelBerger thanks for the feedback. Looking for alternative though (if there are any).

Answer (score 3):

While I share the enthusiasm for CPAN, I think that if there isn't something obvious that works, and you don't care about portability away from linux, then I would just do

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

...

system( q# genisoimage -V 'Name_of_DVD' -dvd-video -o dvd.iso /some_directory # );
```

or as you mention, use [`Filesys::MakeISO::Driver::Mkisofs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aMakeISO%3a%3aDriver%3a%3aMkisofs).
Not trying to be snarky, but CPAN is supposed to be productivity++, but if it doesn't exist, then do what works.

Comment: Wish I could +5 this answer. Perl makes it easy to use the right tool for the job, even when that tool isn't Perl.

Comment: @mob Noted. Just trying to find out if Perl is _NOT_ the right tool.